# how to retrieve profile in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: bash, data-recovery, delete, .profile

I accidentally deleted the .profile in my Ubuntu 18.04 today. How to retrieve this.

regards,

Comment: Which `.profile` file did you delete? your own user's `$HOME/.profile` or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the *default* `$HOME/.profile` that your user account was created with from the `/etc/skel` directory:

```
cp -i /etc/skel/.profile ~/
```

Obviously you will lose any customisations that you made to the file.